# CSS or and JS aggregations all makes site slower!

Tags: css-js-aggregation, performance

It is well known among Drupalists that generally, Aggregation of CSS\JS files should hasten webpage loading times in Drupal... So why the opposite is true for my site this time?

- [PSI](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) test score for my Drupal 7.37 site after No Aggregation whatsoever: 72/100
- PSI test score with CSS aggregation only: 59/100
- PSI test score with JS Aggregation only: 70/100
- [PSI test score with Both file types
  aggregation](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.beniaharon.co.il%2F%25D7%2599%25D7%2599%25D7%25A2%25D7%2595%25D7%25A5-%25D7%25A9%25D7%2599%25D7%2595%25D7%2595%25D7%25A7%25D7%2599-%25D7%259C%25D7%25A7%25D7%2599%25D7%2593%25D7%2595%25D7%259D-%25D7%2590%25D7%2595%25D7%25A8%25D7%2592%25D7%25A0%25D7%2599-%25D7%25A0%25D7%259B%25D7%2595%25D7%259F-%25D7%2591%25D7%259E%25D7%25A0%25D7%2595%25D7%25A2%25D7%2599-%25D7%2597%25D7%2599%25D7%25A4%25D7%2595%25D7%25A9&tab=mobile): 67/100

Bottom line: the natural aggregation options do the opposite of their inherit aim --- They are slowing my site instead of hasting it! Any reasons you could suggest for such wired behavior? Thx.

[image]

Comment: You need to be more specific on what degrades your site's speed. These scores usually come with comments, like in Yslow, then you can compare and identify what improved or worsened your site's performance. You also need to play around with the settings of the module to see what fits your performance needs.

Comment: What do you think I can be more specific about? I gave the exact PSI grades for every situation with a link that mainly say "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content", what aggregation should help with. And what module are you talking about? I used all the relevant options this core module offers for aggregation.

Comment: @benos You have some confusion here - aggregation's sole purpose is to concatenate files, there's literally nothing about it that would help to "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content". To do that, you need to optimise the actual _code_, the order in which scripts are concat'd together (using hook_cs/jss_alter()), move above-the-fold CSS inline, and all the other things you would need to do to solve this problem on any site, not just one that's built on Drupal

Comment: How can I easily find out what is the Above-the-fold CSS or JS that causing this? Is there any tool for it?

Comment: I use browser dev tools personally, my eye, and whatever "critical path" css tool is at the top of google that day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing [PSI](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) and webpage loading times; they are not the same thing.

PSI is series of benchmarks for optimizing performance. It's a checklist Google provides to give you suggestion for improving performance. It doesn't gauge what your site's actual speed is. Use your browser's network activity inspector if you'd like to analyze site load times against CSS/JS aggregation.

Comment: Shawn, we would agree that high PSI score generally correlates with faster loading times. How could you explain the worsening in score after activating any type of natural Drupal aggregation?

Comment: Yes, correlated, but it's not a guage of speed performance. Without seeing the difference in benchmark results, there's no way to tell what caused it. You can compare the bulleted list to find that.

Comment: He couldn't @benos, not without seeing the js before aggregation, after aggregation, and in the context of your running site. No one could. Without those things you're asking for a wild guess, which isn't what Q+A is for. You need to audit your site's front end to find the specific problem, there's no quick-fix

Comment: Could editing the question and add links to each result, or, in the worst case re asking the question may be of any help?

Comment: I'm afraid what you're looking for is a support forum - this is Q+A, so specific, narrowly-scoped, objectively answerable questions, with specific answers. Our format doesn't support the sort of collaborative debugging that would be necessary to help you identify a problem like this. It needs to be attacked by someone sitting in front of the code, with a development environment, tools in hand to debug, and a good knowledge of how to use those tools. I wish you well, but I doubt you'll get the help you're looking for here, most of what you need to know isn't actually related to Drupal